# Jquery Keypress recognized after second press

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="search_text" type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" size="30">
        <div class="form_control" id="search_info" style="width:283px;height:125px;top:86%;position:absolute;background-color:white; border: 1px solid #dce4ec;border-radius: 4px;display:none;"></div>
    </div>
   </form>

$("#search_text").keypress(function (){
    if($("#search_text").val().length == 0)
    {
        $("#search_info").hide();
    }
    else if($("#search_text").val().length != 0)
    {
        $("#search_info").show();
    }
});
```

My issue is that with this code it will only show 
    $("#search_info") 
on the 2nd keypress. For example if i'm typing to the search field which I have as 
  $("#search_text"), $("#search_info") should show on the first press but it does not, when I more than one character into the search field it then shows $("#search_info").

I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/bmcoutvb/

Comment: It might be chrome but I was still only able to see it after the second keypress.

Comment: try using keyup although it works fine for me in multiple browsers as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `keyup` instead of `keypress` - as when keypress fires the value has not been inserted into the input yet.

```
$("#search_text").keyup(function (){
    if($("#search_text").val().length == 0)
    {
        $("#search_info").hide();
    }
    else if($("#search_text").val().length != 0)
    {
        $("#search_info").show();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qxh3x2s6/